# How to download static website with WGET including its CSS, JS, Images in separate folders

Tags: web-scraping, terminal, subdomain, hosting, wget

The website loads its assets from some other domain & I am not able to download those assets at all.(JS, CSS, Images, etc)

Say the website is `example.com` & it includes assets from, say, `assets.orange.com`.

How do I tell WGET to download those assets, save it into different folders(js, css, images) and convert the links in the downloaded HTML files?

I don't know what I am doing wrong & where to specify `assets.orange.com` in this command.

```
wget \
         --mirror \
       --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains example.com \
     --no-parent \
         example.com
```

Comment: Possible answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031147/how-to-download-a-full-website?rq=1

Comment: @Paulo Just tried this but for some reason the CDN site is not getting connected. Here is the error:


Connecting to assets.website-files.com (assets.website-files.com)|2600:9000:2181:2e00:11:3b84:d200:93a1|:443... failed: Resource temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Looks like that the problem is not with wget command, but with the server. The server is refusing your connection. I tried assets.website-files.com and it also denied my connection for some reason, without any error code/message. If this webserver is denying all connections it can mean that it is trying to prevent someone to copy its files.

Comment: @Paulo you are right. I realized the same.  I put in the right CDN address but it's downloading HTML files only. Anyway we can talk over a chat?

Answer (score 1):

*where to specify `assets.orange.com` in this command*

[wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html) says that `--domains` usage is

```
-D domain-list
--domains=domain-list
```

where domain-list is a comma-separated list of domains, so if you wish to specify more than one you should do

```
--domains=example.com,assets.orange.com
```

According to [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html) if you aim to *to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page* you might use

```
-p
--page-requisites
```

Beware that *This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.*

Comment: I used all of these options and none of them are working. `--page-requisites`  just downloads HTML files and doesn't download assets.